# Can't get the return value from a PHP class function

Tags: javascript, php

I used an online converter to turn the Javascript* at http://7xl.org/_msg/mugenzaru into PHP. The code is valid but I don't know how to make the function $mugenzaru->doIt return the variable $resultString. Any ideas?

- a Јapanеse Ⅼоrem Іpsum gеnerator

Original Javascript: http://7xl.org/_msg/mugenzaru/js.htm

Generated and slightly adapted PHP: http://7xl.org/_msg/mugenzaru/php.htm

Comment: note: codes must be posted and included in your question

Comment: I think you will have more success if you move the functions into the classes.

Comment: @Ghost
As per Rasclatt it seems that I couldn't include the code bc it contains Japanese chars that trigger a spam alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences in how "equivalent" php functions work, so there are problems there, specifically the `pickOne()` calculation. `Math.random()` does not work the same as `random()` so the number is way off. See if this gets you closer. One note, the Japanese characters are causing SO to think its spam, so i left those out but they do need to be filled in those arrays:

```
class   Characters
    {   
        private $mugenzaru;

        public  function getString(Mugenzaru $mugenzaru,$charType = 'kangi')
            {
                $this->mugenzaru    =   $mugenzaru;
                $kanji              =   array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4);
                $hiragana           =   array(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4);
                $katakana           =   array(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7);
                $punctuation        =   array(1);
                $lengthWeighting    =   ${$charType};
                $charStringLength   =   $this->mugenzaru->eenieMeenie()->pickOne($lengthWeighting);
                $resultString       =   "";
                while ($charStringLength != 0) {
                    $resultString .= $this->mugenzaru->eenieMeenie()->pickOne($this->mugenzaru->{$charType}());
                    $charStringLength--;
                }
                return $resultString;
            }
    }

class   EenieMeenie 
    {
        public  function pickOne($characterList)
            {
                $rand   =   "0.".str_pad(mt_rand(1,9999999999999999),16,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
                $var    =   floor($rand*count($characterList));
                return $characterList[$var];
            }
    }

class Mugenzaru
    {
        private $length =   10;

        public function eenieMeenie()
            {
                return new EenieMeenie();
            }

        public  function __call($name, $args = false)
            {
                $kanji      =   array(/*** array of kanji ***/);
                $hiragana   =   array(/*** array of hiragana ***/);
                $katakana   =   array(/*** array of katakana ***/);
                $punctuation    =   array(/*** array of punctuation ***/);

                return ${$name};
            }

        public  function setLength($num = 1000)
            {
                $this->length   =   $num;
                return $this;
            }

        public  function doIt(Characters $char) {
                $weighting = array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4);
                $resultString = "";
                $targetLength = $this->length;

                while(strlen($resultString) < $targetLength) {
                    $charWeight =   $this->eenieMeenie()->pickOne($weighting);
                    switch ($charWeight){
                        case 1:
                            $resultString .= $char->getString($this,'kanji');
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            $resultString .= $char->getString($this,'hiragana');
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $resultString .= $char->getString($this,'katakana');
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            $resultString .= $char->getString($this,'punctuation');
                            break;
                        default:
                            $resultString .= $char->getString($this,'kanji');
                    }
                }

                return $resultString;
            }
    }


$Mugenzaru  =    new Mugenzaru();
echo $Mugenzaru->setLength(1000)->doIt(new Characters);
```

Comment: Works like a charm at first sight, thanks a lot!! The script seems to have minor kinks in the JS original (eg repeated punctuation marks seem to occur) but I'll iron these out.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's because of the calculation of the `punctuation` array. I made it equal `array(1);` but that is probably not right.

Answer (score 1):

Change all you string appends from `+=` to `.=`

Comment: Thank you, yes, I did that now. Anyway, eg. this `code`"echo $mugenzaru->doIt;"`code` throws an error: "PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Closure could not be converted to string"

Comment: I'm not too sure but maybe you can change this line "echo $mugenzaru->doIt;" to "echo $mugenzaru->doIt();"

Comment: I tried that, result: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Object::doIt()`